# Character encoding issue with my linux install?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, locale, character-encoding

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04.4 64 bits, all seemed to be ok, when I started to work on console I noticed:

- that I couldn't get some accented characters typed in to the console, for example, if I tried to type *é* I would get a *?*
- That neither a `ls` or any other unix commands output would display such characters properly.
- *ANSIX3.4-1968* appeared as default character encoding in terminal, so:

  - I changed the character encoding to UTF-8 at *Set Character Encoding* option in Terminal menu. I can type these special characters properly but can't get other commands to output in a correct way. And I have to change this every time I open a new console.

When I install anything I see this among the outputs and log info:

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = "en_US:en",
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_TIME = "es_MX.UTF-8",
    LC_MONETARY = "es_MX.UTF-8",
    LC_ADDRESS = "es_MX.UTF-8",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "es_MX.UTF-8",
    LC_NAME = "es_MX.UTF-8",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "es_MX.UTF-8",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "es_MX.UTF-8",
    LC_NUMERIC = "es_MX.UTF-8",
    LC_PAPER = "es_MX.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
```

Also if I do a typo at any command working from console I get:

```
Sorry, command-not-found has crashed! Please file a bug report at:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/command-not-found/+filebug
Please include the following information with the report:

command-not-found version: 0.2.44
```

My settings at install were only English language and Spanish Keyboard layout. What could it have happened? And how can I fix it *permanently*?

Comment: Did you finally managed to solve this? I'm having the same or a similar issue in Ubuntu 14.04.